# AWS EC2 + Apache Airflow. How to connect to admin panel in browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow

I installed airflow and started it on EC2 Ubuntu:

```
airflow webserver
```

But I cannot get access to admin panel in the browser. I tried:

```
ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
```

But I got message:

```
This site can’t be reached
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needed to tune **Inbound Rules** in **Security Group** for the instance with Ubuntu.

[Image Description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GabHE.png)

Comment: can you plz put details about it, i want to access it from my local ubuntu ,suppose my aws server ip XX.XX.XXX.XXX

Comment: you just have to type XX.XX.XXX.XXX:8080 in your browser

Comment: how do you know what address?

Answer (score 0):

Exposing the Airflow UI to the world is not a great idea. I faced this problem few years ago and created this page [Airflow on AWS EC2](https://medium.com/@itsmeviru/airflow-on-aws-ec2-python-3-virtual-environment-3c85a8b8da0f)

For added security, creating a user & password to login is advisable.

Also check out [Airflow 2.0](https://airflow.apache.org/blog/airflow-two-point-oh-is-here/)

Or simply use Airflow on AWS using [Amazon MWAA](https://aws.amazon.com/managed-workflows-for-apache-airflow/), more on this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-managed-workflows-for-apache-airflow-mwaa/)